# Installing Guides and sample code Xcode loop

Tags: installation, xcode8

Each time I launch Xcode I see

[image: install uodates]

So I click install.

When I go to Xcode>Preferences>Components>Documentation

I see

[image: installing]

Fine I wait until I see it completed and installed with the checkmark.

[image]

However when I then click Check and Install again it again shows
[image]

And again each time i launch Xcode I see
[image]

Please help me understand why there is this loop and how to fix?

Comment: Did you resolve this, I seem to have the same issue

Comment: @FBronner no never did. And I tried everything. :-(